# Import data and use numeric as header

Tags: r

I'm attempting to replicate the output of the SensoMinR package (cartoconsumer). The example data set "hedo.cocktail" in the package appears to contain a number as a header.

```
data(cocktail)
View(hedo.cocktail)
```

However, when I try to import dummy data with the same structure (1, 2, 3,... as a header denoting the number of consumers). The header is automatically added with a "X" by RStudio. The issue is that a dataset containing a "X-header" did not produce the output. Making errors, on the other hand.

`Subscript out of bounds in Mat[rownames(MatH),]`

My guess is that the issue seems to be that the data header does not match the example data set.

Is it possible to import data with numeric as a header?

Here's a sample of my dummy data. Thank you for your suggestions.

senso.cake

```
color   odor    flavor  size
25.000  45.000  25.000  78.000
26.000  56.000  49.000  45.000
27.000  54.000  85.000  45.000
28.000  52.000  98.000  58.000
30.000  58.000  56.000  96.000
31.000  56.000  32.000  96.000
32.000  58.000  56.000  93.000
36.000  59.000  45.000  90.000
```

hedo.cake

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
9   7   7   4   8   9   6   7   8   7
6   4   4   2   4   7   8   7   7   7
7   6   8   7   7   6   7   7   7   6
8   8   6   4   7   8   6   8   6   8
4   5   7   3   8   6   6   8   6   7
7   6   7   3   7   6   6   7   7   8
8   6   8   6   7   7   8   7   4   9
6   3   5   6   4   4   6   7   2   7
```

Comment: Column names cannot be numeric (for data frames), so you will have to transform them to a string first or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your data frame to a matrix.

```
mat <- as.matrix(your_df)
mat <- matrix(data = mat, dimnames = NULL, ncol = ncol(your_df))
```

After which you can simply rbind() whatever header you want to it.

```
mat <- rbind(c(1:ncol(mat)), mat)
```

For example:

```
a <- c(5:8)
b <- c(4:7)
c <- c(3:6)

mat <- matrix(c(a,b,c), ncol = 3)
mat <- rbind(c(1:ncol(mat)), mat)

mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    5    4    3
[3,]    6    5    4
[4,]    7    6    5
[5,]    8    7    6
```